# how to use tool tip to display data that is not part of series in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip

I love tool tip function of highcharts! Yet so far I can only display the data from series to tool tip but not the data outside the series. I was considering to add more series but these added series would end up in the chart, which is not what I want. 
Can anyone help me? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The approach I use to this is adding an additional property to each series datapoint:

```
series:[{
    name:"Example Series",
    data:[{x:1,y:2,tt:"Tooltip for point 1"},{x:2,y:3,tt:"Tooltip for point 2"}]
}]
```

These addition properties are available to the tooltip formatter context

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        if(typeof this.point.tt != 'undefined'){
            return this.point.tt;
        }else{
            return ''+this.x +' / '+ this.y +'';
        }                    
    }
},
```

If you use two element arrays to convey your data, you'll have to convert to objects with x and y properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can access whatever data you like inside the  tooltip formatter, including external variables if they're in scope.

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MgV27/)

```
var extraVariable = "This is not part of the chart"

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return 'The value for <b>'+ this.x +
                '</b> is <b>'+ this.y +'</b>  I\'m also showing this: '+extraVariable;
        }
    },
```

Comment: dear Ben:thank you for the tip. Yet your solution does not really solve my problem. Here this "extravariable" is kind of hard-coded and constant to every data point. Here what I really want is to display another series which is variable to each data point. In theory I could just add another series and they would show up in chart. But it would the chart to busy. This is the whole point of adding additional information to tool tip and they show up only when needed....

Comment: sorry, you're not being clear.  What data exactly do you want to display in this tooltip?

Comment: sorry for not being clear. say I have two series that are plotted on chart: series[{1,2,3,4,5},{3,4,5,6,7}], at the first data point (1,3) I want to add letter A as tool tip, at the second data point (2,4) I want to add letter B as tool tip. Note that [A,B,C,D,E] is associated with the two data series but not charted. How do I get [A, B, C, D, E] talk to the two series of number?

Comment: @user1824893 How are the letters associated?  Where is that data held?

Comment: If A,B,C... are in other array, you can use index of this array and display value in formatter

Comment: @Ben: [A,B,C,D,E] is associated with [1,2,3,4,5] by index so A is always pointing to data point (1,3). Where is that data held is 90% of my question. I suppose that I can put it in another array. But can this array be one of argument of highcharts function just as series? Can I define a customized argument, say SeriesForTip side by side with series?

Comment: @Seb: Can I define such a array for [A,B,C..] as one of arguments for highchart function?